# How to clone private git repository in node.js

Tags: node.js, git, ssh

The idea is the following:

node.js in the application should be able to clone private github repositories using ssh. After User send his/her ssh key, the application could be able to clone his repository.

I think about using GIT_SSH variable to use multiple ssh keys. Can any one tell me how this could be implemented?

Comment: Please add code that you tried so that it can explain the description more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to reconsider the idea of users sending you their private SSH keys. I would be very surprised if anyone would do that.

What you can do instead is to use the **GitHub API** and **deploy keys**, that can be made read only. See:

- https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/keys/
- https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys
- https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

For a good introduction on how you can access Git repos fron Node, see:

- [Manipulating git repositories with Node.js](http://radek.io/2015/10/27/nodegit/) by Radek Pazdera

Examples in that article use **NodeGit**. It has excellent documentation on:

- http://www.nodegit.org/api/